# Symfony Doctrine DBAL Error: Unknown column type "json_array" requested after upgrading to DBAL 3"

Tags: symfony5, dbal

I runed the command composer install in my Symfony project. However, when I attempted to run the command symfony console doctrine:schema:update, I encountered the error message:

`Unknown column type "json_array" requested. Any Doctrine type that you use has to be registered with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType(). You can get a list of all the known types with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::getTypesMap(). If this error occurs during database introspection then you might have forgotten to register all database types for a Doctrine Type. Use AbstractPlatform#registerDoctrineTypeMapping() or have your custom types implement Type#getMappedDatabaseTypes(). If the type name is empty you might have a problem with the cache or forgot some mapping information.`

I then modified my code line `@ORM\Column(type="json_array")` to `@ORM\Column(type="json")`, but the error persisted when I runed `symfony console doctrine:schema:update`

From what I understand, one of the sources of the problem is that when I executed the command composer show doctrine/dbal, it indicated that I was using version `3.8.2`. However, just two days ago, when I executed the same command, I was still using version `2.13.2`.

I came across this article "https://dunglas.dev/2022/01/json-columns-and-doctrine-dbal-3-upgrade/", but unfortunately, I do not fully understand its content.

Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide